# Find the sids of the suppliers who supply every part

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

```
Suppliers(sid, sname, address)
Parts(pid, pname, colour)
Catalog(sid, pid, cost)
```

The answer to 'find all the suppliers who supply every part' is:

```
SELECT  C.sid
  FROM  Catalog C
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT  P.pid
       FROM  Parts P
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT  C1.sid
           FROM  Catalog C1
           WHERE C1.sid = C.sid
             AND C1.pid = P.pid
         )
     )
```

What is an explanation for this answer?

I've heard it explained as 'Find suppliers such that there does not exist
a part that they do not sell', but I'm struggling to see how the following accomplishes that.

```
         SELECT  C1.sid
           FROM  Catalog C1
           WHERE C1.sid = C.sid
             AND C1.pid = P.pid
```

If Catalog is

```
James | Hammer
James | Anvil
James | Wrench
Henry | Hammer
Leroy | Anvil
```

and Part is

```
Hammer
Anvil
Wrench
```

then after the innermost clause what is returned?

Is it

```
James | Hammer
James | Anvil
James | Wrench
Henry | Hammer
Leroy | Anvil
```

and then does NOT EXISTS make it the following?

```
James | --
Henry | Anvil, Wrench
Leroy | Hammer, Wrench
```

How does using the Parts table then subtract these values?

Comment: What is the RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Look at your second query a bit closer.  Where is `C` defined?  This won't work the way you think

Comment: It's defined in the first clause. Does it function similarly to a for loop then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a double nested `NOT EXISTS` query (no really, that's what I've usually seen it called), and it is used specificially to answer this type of quesion, i.e., "Are there any x true for all y?"

[Here's MySQL's page on EXISTS and NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html), which mentions this technique specifically.

First, in the innermost `SELECT` query, you are selecting parts that each store carries.  Then, with the first `NOT EXISTS` clause, you are selecting parts that are NOT carried by each store.  Finally, in the outer `NOT EXISTS` clause, you are selecting stores that returned an empty set for the inner `NOT EXISTS` clause, meaning they carry every part.

[Here is a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f18fe/2) of this query in action.

**A word of warning**: if you are working with SQL, it is always good to think and work in sets, and thinking in linear terms like what is about to follow can get you into trouble quickly.  Don't make it a habit!

However, *sometimes* when trying to figure out a complex query like this, it can help to think of these things as loops.

So, taking the data in the fiddle as an example, we have:

```
suppliers:
sid, name
9, 'AAA'
8, 'BBB'
7, 'CCC'

parts:
pid, name
1, 'wood'
2, 'stone'
3, 'paper'

catalog:
cid, pid, sid
1,1,9
2,2,9
3,1,8
4,1,7
5,2,7
6,3,7
```

So with this data, AAA carries wood and stone, BBB only carries wood, and CCC carries wood, stone, and paper.

Now let's step through the query row by row.  We are selecting from `suppliers`, and we are deciding which rows to include in the result set, so start with the first row in `suppliers`: `9,'AAA'`.  We'll call this row `S` temporarily.  We'll only include this row if there is nothing in the inner result set, so lets take a look at that.

```
suppliers:
sid, name
S => 9, 'AAA'
     8, 'BBB'
     7, 'CCC'
```

This result set is selecting from `parts`, and we are going to go through it row by row.  `S` still equals `9,'AAA'` while we do this.  So start with the first row in `parts`: `1,'wood'`.  We'll call this row `P` for now.  We'll only include this row in this first inner result set if there is nothing in the next level of result set, so let's move there.  Remember that `S` = `9,'AAA'` and `P` = `1,'wood'`.

```
suppliers:
sid, name
S => 9, 'AAA'
     8, 'BBB'
     7, 'CCC'

parts:
pid, name
P => 1, 'wood'
     2, 'stone'
     3, 'paper'
```

This innermost query is selecting from 'catalog'. We're looking for any row, we'll call it `C`, in `catalog` where `C.sid` equals `S.sid` AND `C.pid` equals `P.pid`.  This means that the current supplier carries the part.  We want parts that the current supplier DOESN'T carry, that's why we invert the result set.  We know that `S`'s sid is 9, and we know that `P`'s pid is 1.  Are there any rows in `C` that match that?  The very first row in `C` matches that, so we know that this result set is not empty.

```
suppliers:
sid, name
S => 9, 'AAA'
     8, 'BBB'
     7, 'CCC'

parts:
pid, name
P => 1, 'wood'
     2, 'stone'
     3, 'paper'

catalog:
cid, pid, sid
C => 1,1,9 --Match found! Don't include P in outer result set
     2,2,9
     3,1,8
     4,1,7
     5,2,7
     6,3,7
```

Now jump back to the next outermost loop.  The inner result set was not empty, so we know that `1,'wood` will not be part of this loop's result set.  So we move to the next row in `parts`, `2,'stone'`.  We update the value of `P` to equal this row.  Should we include this row in the result set?  We have to run the inner query again with our new value for `P` (`S` has still not changed).  So we look for any rows in `catalog` with `sid` equal to 9 and `pid` equal to 2.  The second row matches, so there is a result set.

```
suppliers:
sid, name
S => 9, 'AAA'
     8, 'BBB'
     7, 'CCC'

parts:
pid, name
     1, 'wood'
P => 2, 'stone'
     3, 'paper'

catalog:
cid, pid, sid
     1,1,9 
C => 2,2,9 --Match found! Don't include P in outer result set
     3,1,8
     4,1,7
     5,2,7
     6,3,7
```

Jump back to the next outermost loop.  The inner result set was not empty, so `2,'stone'` will not be part of this loop's result set.

When we go through all this again for `3,'paper'`, we find that there are no rows in `catalog` that have `sid = 9` and `pid = 3`.  The innermost result set is empty, so we know to include this value of `P` in the next outermost loop.

```
suppliers:
sid, name
S => 9, 'AAA'
     8, 'BBB'
     7, 'CCC'

parts:
pid, name
     1, 'wood'
     2, 'stone'
P => 3, 'paper'

catalog:
cid, pid, sid
     1,1,9 
     2,2,9 
     3,1,8
     4,1,7
     5,2,7
     6,3,7
C => --No match found, include P in outer result set
```

We have gone through the entire `parts` table at this point, so we have our final result set for the second loop, and it is not empty, which means that we found a part that `S` does not carry, so we know that we cannot include the current value of `S` in our final outer loop's result set.

So we move on to the next row in `suppliers` and start the whole process over:

```
suppliers:
sid, name
     9, 'AAA'
S => 8, 'BBB'
     7, 'CCC'
```

Once we get to `S = 7,'CCC'` we will go through all of these loops, and a match will be found in the inner loop for every value of P that is supplied, which means that that second loop will have an empty set.  We couldn't find any parts that supplier doesn't carry, so that value of `S` is added to the result set, meaning they carry everything!

Comment: I understand. Can you explain what the end part that I highlighted means? 
How is (C1.sid = C.id AND C1.pid = P.pid) different from (C.pid = P.pid). It seems obviously different but I can't see how..

Comment: Things got a bit long, see my expanded answer

Comment: I think I can follow it a bit better.

However in the Parts, WHERE NOT EXISTS.. shouldn't the most innerclause SELECT be an attribute that the table Parts shares?

Comment: The innermost SELECT is joined on P.pid as well as C.cid.  It is connected to both the inner and outer clauses by having both referred to in the WHERE clause.  I am not surprised that you are still a bit confused, I still have a hard time wrapping my head around this particular query structure sometimes.

Comment: Yes, it sure is confusing, but this is helping. I've edited my first post to show which part is still confusing me. Could you take a look please?

Comment: @tryingtolearn made a big edit that kind of steps through things.  Hopefully this is clearer?

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate that! It definitely helped me understand it better. So when running the SELECT P.pid we get the parts that the current supplier doesn't have. And then we return the current supplier when the return output is empty? Where P.pid is empty essentially?

Comment: Right, the second loop was empty because the current supplier had all the parts, so they are returned  in the final result set.

Comment: Exceptional answer, incredibly thourough. Word of warning though, thinking of SQL as row-based is the first bad habit to kick. Thinking in rbar results in horrible code which won't perform. Think set based, and start while learning SQL, makes it so much easier.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Absolutely agreed, but this is a tough query to grasp without some sort of linear explanation.  Those joins back to outer sets in the inner query tend to confuse the heck out of people.

Comment: @PaulGriffin This has helped tremendously. As a beginner it was the negation that really confused me as well as confusing NOT EXISTS with NOT IN. Replacing it with EXISTS and then doing the negation myself after really helped me understand it better. Thanks again!

Comment: @PaulGriffin Hi Paul, just one more thing. Could you give me a simple explanation of why it is necessary to introduce a Catalog C table as well as a Catalog C1 table instead of just using SELECT Parts...NOT EXISTS P.pid = C.pid?