# nested NOT EXIST in SQL

Tags: sql, database, nested, relation, not-exists

I am trying to learn relational query languages and SQL, and the example below really confuses me. Could you please help to explain where shall I start to analysis these nested NOT EXIST (the most outer one?), and what each of them does? Thank you so much!

Note: This is only an example, not a real world application.

> consider Director {name, movie} and Actor{name, movie, role}

```
SELECT 
    d1.name 
FROM 
    Director d1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT d2.movie 
                  FROM Director d2
                  WHERE d2.name = d1.name 
                    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT a1.role 
                                   FROM Actor a1
                                   WHERE a1.name = d2.name 
                                     AND a1.movie = d2.movie 
                                     AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT a2.role 
                                                    FROM Actor a2 
                                                    WHERE a2.role ̸= a1.role
                                                    AND a2.movie = a1.movie 
                                                    AND a2.name= a1.name
                                                   )
                                 )
                  )
```

Comment: I feel like a bit of an ass pointing to this, but I got into a pretty lengthy explanation of this sort of query here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012455/find-the-sids-of-the-suppliers-who-supply-every-part/29013311#29013311

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an extension of one of the formulations for [relational division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29), specifically division-with-remainder.

[This article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) by Joe Celko has a pretty exhaustive explanation of the concept and the various ways you can implement it.

[This fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f055f/1) should give you more of an idea of what's going on.

You can read either direction, but it might be easier to start with the outside in in this case.

You're looking for the director's name for a movie where there is not a movie for the same director where there is not a role played by that director and not another role for the same movie by the same director.

It's hard to cook this down, but as best I can tell, this devolves down to wanting the director's name for all movies where the director appeared as an actor in the movie in exactly one role.

Comment: Many thanks! Could you explain a bit more on how does the second NOT EXIST "WHERE d2.name = d1.name AND NOT EXISTS"works for "where there is not a role played by that director" ? And why use d1 and d2?

Comment: As far as I managed to understand, in `SELECT d2.movie FROM Director d2
      WHERE d2.name = d1.name AND NOT EXISTS(
       SELECT a1.role FROM Actor a1
       WHERE a1.name = d2.name AND a1.movie = d2.movie ` , the NOT EXIST eliminate the directors who played in there movies?

Answer (score 1):

Work from the deepest nested query to the outermost level. As you understand a level, replace it with a plain English description. For example, the innermost level in your query above could be described like this: "Same movie, same actor, different role", or "actor has more than one role in the movie". Working outwards, NOT EXISTS gives us "actor does not have more than one role in the movie". Combine that with the WHERE clause and we get "actor is the director of the movie AND actor does not have more than one role in the movie". Just keep doing that until you reach the top level...

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain a bit more..?  And then what do we get when combine "actor is the director of the movie AND actor does not have more than one role in the movie". with "WHERE d2.name = d1.name AND NOT EXISTS()" ? Also I don't quite understand why it uses d1 and d2.

Comment: d1 and d2 are a "self-join". This enables the overall query to get two different rows from the same table. It's really the same thing as the "actor with more than one role", but for the director.