# Select rows in table A that junction to all of a set of items from table B

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join

Based on [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Mapping_table_concept.png) (forget "genre" though):

I have a list of actors, and need to retrieve a list of films that contain *every* actor on my list.

**Example data:**

```
INSERT INTO actor (actor_id, name) VALUES
    (1, "Alice"), (2, "Bob");

INSERT INTO film (film_id, title) VALUES
    (1, "Star Wars"), (2, "The Matrix"), (3, "Lion King);

INSERT INTO actor_film_mapping (actor_id, film_id) VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2), (2, 2),
    (2, 3);
```

Looking for e.g. List of films containing Alice and Bob should give me only The Matrix

The closest I've come is [this query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ad80/3) which selects films with *any* of my list of actors, rather than ones with *all*.

Looking on StackOverflow for similar answers, I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990684/select-rows-that-have-a-specific-set-of-items-associated-with-them-through-a-jun/29991705#29991705) which works fine in MSSQL but not MySQL.

Hope I've phrased this question OK. I'm new to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close.  Instead of using `select distinct`, do an aggregation and count the number of matches using `having`:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM film f INNER JOIN
     actor_film_mapping afm
     ON f.film_id = afm.film_id
WHERE afm.actor_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY f.film_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: Looks good! So if I was to change the list (or in my case generate it programmatically), would I need to change the COUNT to the length of the list?

Comment: Great answer. I'm still a newby with sql. I was wondering if my sql statement would work: `SELECT film_id, COUNT(film_id) as actor_count 
FROM actor_film_mapping 
GROUP BY film_id 
WHERE actor_count = (SELECT COUNT(actor_id) FROM actor);` I'm not confident enough in it to post an answer.